# Adding to a variable

Tags: javascript

i am trying to add a score to my game, whenever the cube passes through a gap it adds one to score. i have tried a few different methods but none of them worked for me. here is my script, i have all three html, css and javascript in there, sorry if it is a bit messy. thanks.
ps. i have to put more info in to this question to post it

```js
    var ctx
    var pieceX = 200;
    var pieceY = 400;
    var pieceXX = 5; 
    var pieceYY = 5; 
    var length = 200;
    var height = 0;
    var myScore = 0;
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = myScore;

     function init() {

        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        setInterval(draw,10);
        document.getElementById('lose').style.visibility = "hidden";
     }
    function draw() {
     ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
     ctx.beginPath(); 
     ctx.fillStyle = "red";
     ctx.fillRect(pieceX,pieceY,30,30);
     ctx.fill();
  
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.fillStyle = "blue"; 
     ctx.fillRect(0,height,length,30);
     ctx.fill();
  
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
     ctx.fillRect(length + 50,height,500 - (length + 50), 30);
     ctx.fill();
  
     height ++
     if (height > 500) {
       height = 0;
       length = Math.floor(Math.random()*400) + 50;
     }
     if (pieceY == height) {
         if (pieceX < length || pieceX > length + 20) {
            document.getElementById("lose").style.visibility = "visible";
             }
      myScore = myScore + 1;
     
      
                        }
     }

 
     function keyDown() {
       var key = event.keyCode;
      switch (key) {
    case 37 : pieceX -= pieceXX;
      break;
    case 38 : pieceY -= pieceYY;
      break;
    case 39 : pieceX += pieceXX;
      break;
    case 40 : pieceY += pieceYY;
             }
    }
```

```css
    #canvas {
    border: solid;
    }
    #lose {
    position : absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 34%;
    width : 167px;
    background-color: red;
    }
    #score { 
    position : absolute;
    top : -10px;
    left : 90%;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <body onLoad="init()" onkeydown="keyDown()">
      <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
      <h1 id="lose">YOU LOSE</h1>
      <h1 id="score"></h1>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: What is your problem *exacly* ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (pieceY == height) {
     if (pieceX < length || pieceX > length + 20) {
        document.getElementById("lose").style.visibility = "visible";
     }
  //Here add
  myScore = myScore +1;
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = myScore;
}
```

To stop animations (set gameIsOver to true when you want to stop):

```
 var stop,gameIsOver;
 function init() {

    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    stop = setInterval(draw,10);
    document.getElementById('lose').style.visibility = "hidden";
 }
function draw(){
  if(gameIsOver){
    clearInterval(stop);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to stop the draw founction, recording the interval id:

```
var interval_id;

function init() {

  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  document.getElementById('lose').style.visibility = "hidden";
  interval_id = setInterval(draw,10); // to record the interval id
}
```

and clear the interval by that id when lost:

```
if (pieceY == height) {
  if (pieceX < length || pieceX > length + 20) {

    // to stop the draw interval
    clearInterval(interval_id);

    document.getElementById("lose").style.visibility = "visible";
  }

  myScore = myScore + 1;

  // to update the score to the view
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = myScore;
}
```

restart the game:

```
function restart() {

  // reset all variables that changed to it's initial value
  pieceX = 200;
  pieceY = 400;
  height = 0;
  myScore = 0;

  // reset view
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = myScore;
  document.getElementById('lose').style.visibility = "hidden";

  // start the interval loop(it will return a different id)
  interval_id = setInterval(draw, 10); // to record the interval id
}
```

Comment: thanks, just how can i use a function to begin the interval again?

Comment: its okay, i have figured out a way